# How to design a table that has dynamic columns with ItemsControl or ListView or DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to design a table like picture:[image]

The table has 4 row ,first column is row header, when click "Add column" button, a `ColumnConfiguration` will be added to `ColumnConfigurations` and last column will be deleted when i click "delete column" button, corresponding to add and delete a column in table

```
public ObservableCollection<ColumnConfiguration> ColumnConfigurations { get; set; }
```

I want something like:

```
<ItemsControl
            BorderThickness="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
            MaxWidth="500"
            Height="Auto"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ColumnConfigurations}"
            AlternationCount="{Binding ColumnConfigurations.Count}">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dialogs:ColumnConfiguration}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock   Margin="4,0" Text="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
            StringFormat=Column {0}}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="4,0" Text="{Binding ColumnType}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="4,0" Text="{Binding Unit}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="4,0" Text="{Binding Option}" />
            </StackPanel>            
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Please give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

Use DataGrid with AutoGenrateColumns="False", set your Columns directly.

DataGrid is what you are looking for:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx